# How to show that the $ax+b$ group is locally compact?

Tags: topological-groups, linear-groups

Let $ax+b$ be the group of affine transformations $x\mapsto ax+b$ with $a>0$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$.  How do you topologize this group?  As a group it is isomorphic to the set of $2$x$2$ matrices of the form \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.  But unless I am greatly mistaken this set of matrices connot be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ since two entries are fixed.  So how do you argue that $ax+b$ is a locally compact group?

Comment: Identify it with $(0,\infty)\times\Bbb R$.

Comment: Every open subspace of a locally compact space is also locally compact, as you are aware of, but the same also applies to **closed** subspaces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be your group and consider the bijection$$\begin{array}{rccc}\psi\colon&(0,\infty)\times\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&G\\&(a,b)&\mapsto&\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.\end{array}$$Then, consider the distance defined on $G$ by $d(M,N)=\bigl\|\psi^{-1}(M)-\psi^{-1}(N)\bigr\|.$

Comment: Just to be clear, this map is not a homeomorphism between $(0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ and $G$ considered as a subset of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ correct?

Comment: It *is* a homeomorphism.

Comment: But then wouldn't $G$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ since the topology on $GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is just the Euclidean topology?

Comment: No. Why would $G$ be open in $\Bbb R^4$ then?

Comment: Ah nevermind you are right

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

$a>0, b\in \mathbb{R}$ gives you a pretty obvious homeomorphism with the (open) upper halfspace. Is that locally compact?

Answer (score 0):

The topology on this group is inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$, and when identified in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it is an open half-plane. Definitely locally-compact.